# How to use AngularJS directive for WURFL img-wit with ng-src?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, image-size, wurfl

http://www.scientiamobile.com/page/angularwit

Want to be able to do something like this:

```
<img-wit ng-src="{{trustSrc(profile.pic)}}" w="100"/>
```

The picture isn't rendering however, although the blank space is sized correctly.  Is it possible to use angular directive version of img-wit with ng-src?

UPDATE:

Determined the easiest way to use img-wit is not to implement angularjs directive at all.  Instead, just append appropriate img-wit link prefix inside controller.

Comment: not in the current implementation of the directive. It [just looks for a `src` attribute immediately upon initialisation](https://github.com/WURFL/angular-wurfl-image-tailor/blob/master/src/angular-wurfl-image-tailor.js), which won't work with `ng-src` since the `src` attribute won't be immediately available.

Comment: Hi, Luca Passani, ScientiaMobile CTO here.

I just noticed this post now (for some reason, I don't seem to have received a notification when this was posted to SO). We discussed this with the engineer. We will add support for ng-src. Please stay tuned. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Support to ngSrc directive has been added in the 0.9.1 version: https://github.com/WURFL/angular-wurfl-image-tailor/releases/tag/0.9.1.

Syntax like the follow is now supported:

```
<img-wit ng-src="{{myUrl}}"></img-wit>
```

where {{myUrl}} is the url of the trusted image to load.

Please check https://github.com/WURFL/angular-wurfl-image-tailor#how-to-use-it for further details.

*Disclaimer: I work for ScientiaMobile*

Comment: Hi lucor,  thanks!  that's awesome!  I will let you know once I've implemented it.

Comment: Hi lucor, I'm hoping to use the wurfl image tailor service to display profile pictures on a social media site.  However, I don't see a way to trigger cache refresh.  If a user updates their profile photo, is there some way to request a cache refresh?

Comment: Hi @claireablani, you can query string your image adding a random number or a version like `profile.png?v1`

Comment: Hi @lucor, I'm able to correctly use the imgWit directive for angular as described in the documentation.  However, what I really need is to use imgWit with ng-src, rather than a hard-coded src string.  Is that possible?

Comment: @lucor: thanks for your response regarding cache.  I decided to append the 'lastSaved' timestamp - similar to random string but a little less random.

Comment: Yes, you can use ng-src starting from version 0.9.1, please see for details https://github.com/WURFL/angular-wurfl-image-tailor#how-to-use-it